# Meta symbol for existential quantification in Isabelle

Tags: isabelle

There are meta symbols for implication and universal quantification in Isabelle/Pure (`⟹` and `⋀`), which behave differently from its HOL counterparts (∀ and →).

Is there a meta symbol for existential quantification? If not, is there a specific reason for this decision?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pure is based on intuistionistic logic and there is no existential quantifier in this logic.

The rough equivalent is `obtains`:

```
lemma
  assumes "P"
  obtains x where "Q x"
```

The generated lemma is `P ⟹ (⋀x. Q x ⟹ thesis) ⟹ thesis`. It does not contain an existential quantifier, but only an implication. However it plays a similar rule: by instantiation of `thesis` with any other goal, you can exhibit the existence of an `x` such that `Q x`.

Comment: For those still a bit confused: `P ⟹ (⋀x. Q x ⟹ thesis) ⟹ thesis` is roughly equivalent to `P → ∃x. Q x` in *HOL*.